# jquery selector in angular10 is hitting 'select2:unselecting' on dropdown select

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, dropdown, angular10

We have a single select dropdown in angular 10 application, where the first single select is firing the 'select2:unselecting' event, which is incorrect.

```
$(el.nativeElement).select2({
      data: this.data: [],
      matcher: matcher
    }).on('change', (e: Event) => {
      ...
      ...
    }).on('select2:unselecting', (e: Event) => {
      ...
      ...
    }
    });
```

Any idea why unselect event is getting fired?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery with Angular and what are you trying to achieve?